# How to read/write a zip file without loading the whole thing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a project that needs to deal with some humungous zip-files. These have both a large number of files in them and also take up a lot of space on the disk. One thing's for certain: they can't be loaded into my ancient MacBook's RAM. I know that I can read from the zip without fully decompressing it by using a library such as `random-access-zip`, but I also need a way to write new files/folders into the zip file. Is there any library that can do this? Or is there some other archive format that is suited for random access?

Comment: Compressed files in general are poor choice when you need to read and write to them simultaneously or when you need random access. A strategy in memory constrained environments is read the file sequentially, parsing and updating the content as it comes through, writing out and compressing the changed content to a new file.

Comment: @Ouroborus do you know of a library that can do that?

Comment: @Ouroborus I also don't necessarily need the files to be compressed, they just have to be collected into a single archive file